# Trying to create mobileapp store using WSO2 ES

Tags: android, wso2

I am trying to create a Mobile App store using WSO2 ES.I am able to host it on a PC and access from another, register user , login as user, login as admin and download "ebook" assets on my smartphone from the store. I have been able to publish a "mobileapp" asset on the publisher URL(https://192.xxx.xx.xx:9443/publisher).
 All is good till here but I do not know how I can actually upload my app(.apk file) on the server. I also cannot see "mobileapp" section in the store URL([http://192.xxx.xx.xx:9763/store).I](http://192.xxx.xx.xx:9763/store%29.I) think I am missing something from the official documentation.It would be helpful if somebody could just point out what steps I need to do in order to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you have missed on creating correct RXT for Mobile apps. WSO2 ES is a generic store and if you want to add any customize options you need to define as you want.

Here is the official guide: http://docs.wso2.com/display/ES100/Adding+a+New+Asset+Type

Also check this blog for further simplification:

```
 http://udarakr.blogspot.com/2013/11/deploy-your-own-enterprise-store-part-1.html
 http://udarakr.blogspot.com/2013/11/deploy-your-own-enterprise-store-part-2.html
 http://udarakr.blogspot.com/2013/11/deploy-your-own-enterprise-store-part-3.html
```

Comment: I have published by mobile app from publisher. Updated the state to publish.
 But cannot see my published app in the store. I cannot even create any separate 
 tab for "mobileapps" as shown for "mp3"in the link by you. I have made changes
 to "publisher" and "store" json both through file manager and in registry from carbon console.
 But nothing helps me to create that new tab for "mobileapps". Another doubt that I have is if I need 
 Mobile Manager to upload by .apk(android) or I can do it by just using Enterprise store.

Comment: were you able to solve this issue? Have you tried restarting ES server?